# How to create object for TableName for passing it in truncateTable() method in hBase

Tags: hbase

How do I create object for the class TableName and pass the Table name , which is required for truncateTable() method.

below is the code that I am trying to execute.

```
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(hbaseConfiguration);


admin.truncateTable(tableName, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using static methods of TableName class like below;

```
admin.truncateTable(TableName.valueOf("your_table_name"), true);
```